# NSDecimalNumber sum

Tags: ios, core-data, sum, key-value-coding, nsdecimalnumber

In my ios project I use two entities (**CoreData**): Person and Gifts with To-Many Relationship

I know how to calculate the sum of gifts to one person:

```
NSDecimalNumber *orderSum=[person.gifts valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.priceOfGift"];
```

But how do I calculate the sum of all persons?

```
 -(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
//NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nameOfPerson"
                                                               ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"nameOfGroup" cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

Comment: Just fetch all of the pesrons

Comment: Can you give an simple example...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sum of all persons" would be to fetch all persons and count them

```
int sum = fetchedObjects.count;
```

But perhaps you mean the "sum of the prices of all gifts of all persons". If you think about it, it is the same as the sum of the prices of all gifts. Thus, you can just fetch the gifts and calculate

```
NSNumber *sum = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects 
      valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.priceOfGift"];
```

Comment: Dear Mundi thanks for your response. Please take a look at the updated code, how i can use : NSNumber *sum = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.priceOfGift"]; Thank you

Comment: `fetchedObjects` is a property of `NSFetchedResultsController`.  See above.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber *sum = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
                     valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.priceOfGift"];
    totalLabel.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:sum];
    NSLog(@"%@ Sum ", sum); 
In the console, I get a (null) Sum

Comment: Go ahead and debug. Is price of gift NSNumber? No spelling mistakes? Double check the managed object subclass declarations, etc.

Comment: price of gift - NSDecimalNumber. No Spelling mistakes. Sorry but what exactly should I check the managed object subclass declarations?

Comment: The attribute should be of type NSNumber. In .m file it should be `@dynamic`. You should verify that there are valid numbers to be summed in the database (e.g. via NSLog).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21475/discussion-between-astakhoff-and-mundi)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch all the Persons, then use the sum

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    request.predicate = nil;
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES]];//some parameter
    NSArray *persons =  [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 NSDecimalNumber *orderSum;
 for (Person *person in persons)
  orderSum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:orderSum.decimalValue
+[person valueForKeyPath:@"gifts.@sum.priceOfGift"].decimalValue]
```

Though, now work with NSDecimalNumber look a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSDecimal' and 'id')

Comment: Just take the decimal value